# color code passed to flash variable in Twitter badge

Tags: php, flash, twitter

I'm trying to create a simple interface to automate the creation of a flash twitter badge for a WordPress theme.

My question is this, on the [twitter page which has a simple color customizer](http://twitter.com/widgets/compact_flash_widget), the standard hex color codes are getting translated to something to be passed to the flash as a variable.

Can anyone shed any light on what that color code system is?  And possibly how I might write a PHP function to translate a six-digit hex code into that system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are passing the hex color value as decimal. E.g:

```
(16711680)base10 = (FF0000)base16 = (red)base-layman
(0)base10        = (0)base16      = (black)base-layman
```

You don't need any special magic in PHP as far as I can tell. This is a matter of representation and not of encoding.

Hope that helps!